# Amazon ALB: How to set up HTTPs listener without a custom domain

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I want to set up an AWS Application Load Balancer with an HTTPs listener so I can integrate with OIDC.

I don't need a custom domain.

To set up HTTPs, I need a certificate. How do I get a certificate for the default domain name (something like `my-alb-000000000.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`)?

I don't think I can use ACM for that but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, you need to use TLS certificate of some kind with ALB to use HTTPS.

Comment: AWS support confirmed this, too. Thanks.