# Why is it not possible to create an ALB with HTTPS listener without a custom domain (and its TLS certificate)?

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer

I want to add an HTTPS listener to my AWS Application Load Balancer. I see from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105904/amazon-alb-how-to-set-up-https-listener-without-a-custom-domain) that it's not possible without a custom domain (and the certificate that authenticates it). My question is why? Couldn't there be a certificate belonging to AWS, and it would certify, when people connect to my ALB, that "yes you are indeed talking in HTTPS with domain blabla.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: I find this actually annoying, with cloudfront, aws provides a default ssl certificate which you can use so you can have https without needing to use your own custom domain, but for elb, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You need a certificate to create a listener for your ALB, certificate manager can help you and public certificates are free, you need a custom domain to validate that you are the owner of that or you can upload your own certificate.

Comment: The point is you shouldn't need a custom domain. The ALB already has a DNS entry - why can't AWS simply provide a certificate for it?